# Making a class more generic

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Here's some code I've inherited for a game. The sample code creates Armor.

At the moment to make some new Armor, you need to write a new class. E.g.

```
// Armor.java
public class Armor extends Item {   
    public int tier;

    public Armor( int tier ) {
        this.tier = tier;
    }
}
```

and

```
// ClothArmor.java    
public class ClothArmor extends Armor {
    {   
        name = "Cloth armor";
    }

    public ClothArmor() {
        super( 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public String desc() {
        return "Some Cloth Armor.";
    }
}
```

How would you structure the code to make it more generic? It would seem obvious to just read from a text-based config file but I can see this running into problems when you wanted to create an Armor with special abilities for example.

Are there any resources or design patterns I can use to figure out how to proceed?

Comment: What exactly you need here and what are you trying to do and how are you going to use this class?

Comment: Here what are you meaning by 'generic'?

Comment: You mean load code from a text file? Short answer: that's not possible in Java.

Comment: Of course this is possible. Two versions: **1.** Java Code in a Text file that gets compiled at run time (can become complicated). **2.** write your item in form of JSON to a text file, use Jackson or Gson to parse the contents of the file and map it to some Java Object. Pretty simple.

Comment: @BenjaminM your second optin wouldn't load code. It would load data.

Comment: Yes, right. But these are 2 possibilities to store the items in external text files, either as code or as data. All in all i'd prefere a NoSQL store for such things, because I think those items might get more complex and might have completely different characteristics. Then load them on application start from DB, create Java Objects and work with that.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to add dynamically some behaviour to an `Armor`, you can use the **Decorator** design pattern. Try to have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). It is one of the most used pattern of GoF's book, *Design Patterns*.

So, if I do understand well your needs, you can read from a file the properties you want to add to a base `Armor` and then, using a *factory*, add them to the armor using the *decorator* pattern.

```
interface Armor {
    // Put public interface of Armor here
    public String desc();
}
class BaseArmor extends Item implements Armor {
    public int tier;
    public BaseArmor( int tier ) {
        this.tier = tier;
    }
    public String desc() {
        return "A base armor ";
    }
}
// Every new possible feature of an armor has to extend this class
abstract class ArmorDecorator implements Armor {
    protected final Armor armor;
    // The armor that we want to decorate
    public ArmorDecorator(Armor armor) {
        this.armor = armor;
    }
}
// An armor that is made of cloth
class MadeOfCloth extends ArmorDecorator {
    public MadeOfCloth(Armor armor) {
        super(armor);
    }
    @Override
    public String desc() {
        // Decoration: we add a feature to the desc method
        return armor.desc() + "made of Cloth ";
    }
}
// The factory that reads the properties file and build armors
// using the information read.
enum ArmorFactory {
    INSTANCE;
    public Armor build() {
        Armor armor = null;
        // At this point you have to had already read the properties file
        if (/* An armor made of cloth */) {
            armor = new MadeOfCloth(new BaseArmor(1));
        }
        return armor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always tempting to add more levels to a type hierachy to add functionality. But that is not always the best path. Sometimes the best path is to determine the orthogonal features and extract them instead. The key here is preferring composition rather than inheritance.

So in this case I'd think about how is a `ClothArmour` different from `Armour`, and how is `Armour` different from `Item`? I'd say `ClothArmour` differs from Armour in what it is made from, and the bonuses it applies. Then I'd say Armour differentiates from Item by the location it equips to.

Then I'd consider getting rid of `ClothArmour` and `Armour` altogether.

```
Item clothArmour = new Item( 
                            EquipLocation.Chest, 
                            ComponentType.Cloth,
                            Bonuses.defenceOnEquip(1) );
```

Why is this an improvement? It seems much less object oriented. Well loading or saving this format is relatively trivial.